# Splitting number in list in K equal parts

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, logic

I am trying to solve a problem in which I am dividing a list stick into equal size given by K.

**Input: stick = [5, 9, 7], K = 4**

This means that we have three sticks with lengths as 5, 9 and 7. We would like to come up with K=4 equal length sticks by cutting these three sticks. We would like to end up with K=4 equal length sticks.

**Updated Explanation:**

From the first stick with length 5, we can have one stick with length 4.

From the second stick with length 9, we can have two sticks with length 4.

From the third stick with length 7, we can have one stick with length 4.

My code is below:

```
stick = [5,7,9]
K=4
for i in range(len(stick)):
    T = stick[i]%K
    if T !=0:
        print (stick[i],T)
    else:
        print (stick[i])
```

My code is giving me the below output

```
5 1
7 3
9 1
```

but how I can print the number + its addition like

```
5 = 4 + 1
7 = 4 + 3
9 = 4*2 + 1
```

My code is only giving me output `1,3,1`

Expected output:

```
Input: stick = [5, 9, 7], K = 4
Output: 4

Explanation:
Cut arr[0] = 5 = 4 + 1
Cut arr[1] = 9 = 2 * 4 + 1
Cut arr[2] = 7 = 4 + 3
```

Example 2:

```
Input: stick[] = {5, 9, 7}, K = 3
Output: 5 \

Explanation:
Cut arr[0] = 5 = 5
Cut arr[1] = 9 = 5 + 4
Cut arr[2] = 5 = 5 + 2
```

Comment: To be clear, we are specifically looking for integer results?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `stick[i]%K` to compute - given that `stick[i]` is the length of one of the original sticks, and `K` is the total number of desired resulting sticks? What is your intended approach to the problem - how would you solve it by hand, using pencil and paper?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Note that they have already solved the problem. The question is about presenting the results.

Comment: Not really? It just happens by coincidence here that the correct stick length is equal to the number of desired sticks.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You might be right. The question is a bit vague as it is stated. "I am dividing a list stick into equal size given by K" sounds like `K` is the length, but then another sentence makes it sound like it is the number of splits.

Comment: K is a number of splits

Comment: In that case @KarlKnechtel is right, you don't only have a printing issue but your code does not calculate the correct values either.

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I am trying to create a logic and thinking about it

Answer (score -1):

It is best to construct a string depending on different conditions and print that instead:

```
stick = [5, 7, 8, 9]
K = 4
for i in range(len(stick)):
    T = stick[i] % K
    D = stick[i] // K

    # Construct the multiplier text (* ...) if necessary
    if D > 1:
        multiplier = f" * {D}"
    else:
        multiplier = ""

    # Construct the remainder (+ ...) text if necessary
    if T:
        remainder = f" + {T}"
    else:
        remainder = ""

    # Print the final result
    print(f"{stick[i]} = {K}{multiplier}{remainder}")
```

This should print:

```
5 = 4 + 1
7 = 4 + 3
8 = 4 * 2
9 = 4 * 2 + 1
```

Update: This answer assumes that `K` is the desired length as hinted in the original code posted in the question. If it is the number of splits the logic must be updated accordingly, but the answer to your actual question (i.e. *"how to print in a specific way"*) stays the same.